# How do I clone a xml element using Linq to Xml

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I would like to clone a Xml element, insert it to the end of the element list and save the document. Could someone explain how it is done in linq to xml

#### Xml

```
  <Folders>
    <Folder ID="1" Name="Music" PathValue="Root/Music" ParentId="0"></Folder>
    <Folder ID="2" Name="Rock" PathValue="Root/Rock" ParentId="1"></Folder>
  </Folders>
```

#### Context

think of the xml element Folder as Virtual folder on disk. I would like to copy the folder Rock into music hence the resulting xml should become as below

#### Result Required

```
  <Folders>
    <Folder ID="1" Name="Music" PathValue="Root/Music" ParentId="0"></Folder>
    <Folder ID="2" Name="Rock" PathValue="Root/Rock" ParentId="0"></Folder>
    <Folder ID="3" Name="Rock" PathValue="Root/Music/Rock" ParentId="1"></Folder>
  </Folders>
```

#### Operations to be carried out

1. Clone the source node ( Done #1)
2. Clone the other nodes inside source node ( Don't know how to do it #2)
3. Generate new ID for the nodes inside #2 and change pathvalue ( I know how to do this)
4. Insert the **node** #1 and **nodes** from #2 ( Don't know)

#### 1

```
var source = new XElement((from folder in _xmlDataSource.Descendants("Folders").Descendants("Folder") where
wallet.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals(sourceWalletId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) select wallet).First());
//source is a clone not the reference to node.
```

#### 2

```
var directChildren = (from folder in _xmlDataSource.Descendants("Folders").Descendants("Folder") where folder.Attribute("PathValue").Value.Contains(sourcePathValue) select folder);
//How do i clone this
```

#### Question

Could someone help me with #2 and #4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know about the constructor that takes another XElement to create a copy of it, have you tried this?

```
var copiedChildren = from folder in _xmlDataSource.Descendants("Folders").Descendants("Folder") 
                     where folder.Attribute("PathValue").Value.Contains(sourcePathValue) 
                     select new XElement(folder);
```

as you have already cloned `source`, you can insert those into that node (assuming they should be children of the copied node)

Answer (score 3):

If you're only concerned with copying elements nested inside the source element, you could use this:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument("filename");
XElement source = xdoc.Root.Elements("Folder").Where(f => f.Attribute("ID") == "1").First();
XElement target = new XElement(source);
target.Add(new XAttribute("ParentId", source.Attribute("ID"));

// TODO update ID and PathValue of target
xdoc.Root.Add(target);
```